# List a range of multiple columns and rows into a single column

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Surely there is a more concise way to accomplish this:

```
=UNIQUE({F2:F;G2:G;H2:H;I2:I;J2:J;K2:K;L2:L;M2:M;N2:N;O2:O;P2:P;Q2:Q;R2:R;S2:S;T2:T;U2:U;V2:V;W2:W;X2:X;Y2:Y;Z2:Z})
```

I've also tried a query, but don't know how to merge all of the columns into a single column:

```
=QUERY(F2:Z,"SELECT *",0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(F2:Z<>"", "♦"&F2:Z, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")))))
```